# JAVA Can someone explain this code for me? Auto-Gen

Tags: java, random, passwords, temporary

I found these codes online at:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Security/GeneratearandomStringsuitableforuseasatemporarypassword.htm

But I am not really sure about the codes' logic.

```
public static String generateRandomPassword()
{

      String letters = "abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ23456789";

      String pw = "";
      for (int i=0; i<PASSWORD_LENGTH; i++)
      {
          int index = (int)(RANDOM.nextDouble()*letters.length());
          pw += letters.substring(index, index+1); 
      }
      return pw;
}
```

Can someone explain this two lines of codes for me so I can understand better?

```
int index = (int)(RANDOM.nextDouble()*letters.length());
pw += letters.substring(index, index+1);
```

Thank You. :D

Comment: Which part of the code is confusing you?

Comment: A RANDOM letter (or digit) is picked and then added to `pw` in the line with `+=`.

Comment: What confuses you? Did you take a look what values can be returned by `RANDOM.nextDouble()`? Do you know what `letters.length()` mean? Assuming that `nextDouble` would return only values between `[0; 1)` what value could be result of `RANDOM.nextDouble()*letters.length()`? What if we cast it to `int`? Do you know what `+=` stands for? Or what `substring` does?

Comment: Anyway `int index = (int)(RANDOM.nextDouble()*letters.length());` should be replaced with `int index = RANDOM.nextInt(letters.length());` for readability and `String pw` with `StringBuilder pw` for performance (`pw.append(..)` instead of `pw+=...`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int index = (int)(RANDOM.nextDouble()*letters.length());` Generates a random double greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0. Then it multiples the result by the length of your string of acceptable letters. Essentially, in these two steps, you have number between 0 (inclusive) and the total number of valid "letters", but it is a double, so it has a decimal part. That number is casted to an int (a whole number) and saved into the `index` variable.

`pw += letters.substring(index, index+1);` Concatenates `pw` with a substring of the `letters` string. The substring begins at the index determined by the line above and ends at `index + 1` (not including the character at `index + 1`). Essentially, this part makes a substring of one character at the index determined by the random integer generated above. It then concatenates it onto the existing `pw` string.

Example of steps:

`int index = (int)(RANDOM.nextDouble()*letters.length());`:

1. `RANDOM.nextDouble()` => 0.51
2. `letters.length()` => 60
3. `RANDOM.nextDouble()*letters.length()` => 30.6
4. `(int)(RANDOM.nextDouble()*letters.length())` => 30

`pw += letters.substring(index, index+1);`:

1. `letters.substring(index, index+1)` => "H"
2. `pw += letters.substring(index, index+1)` => "" + "H" => "H"

Answer (score 0):

This line will give you the index of the "letter" in the array `letters`.

`int index = (int)(RANDOM.nextDouble()*letters.length());`

Because [RANDOM.nextDouble()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextDouble%28%29) will return a "fraction" (0.0d (inclusive) to 1.0d (exclusive)) which is multiplied by the size, which is the last index + 1, hence it will always give a proper index.

`pw += letters.substring(index, index+1);`

Will add the letter at the index `index` to the password.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I got it now :D

Answer (score 0):

Think of letters as a character array instead of a String.  This will help you to understand.

```
RANDOM.nextDouble()
```

Will create a random double from range 0.0 to 1.0.  It is then multiplied by the length of your String (character array) to give a number between 0.0 and the last index of your array.

```
(int)
```

Will cast this number to an integer type, which will chop off the decimal, leaving you with a whole number.  This number is then saved to index.

```
pw += letters.substring(index, index+1);
```

Cuts out a segment of the letters String between the index, and the index after that one.  Essentially, it just grabs the character at that index, and adds it to your pw String.

The function then returns your pw string, which is a randomly generated String with possible characters in the letters String, with a length of PASSWORD_LENGTH

Comment: Thank you so much Michael, I understand it now :D

Answer (score 0):

People already explained the code. But I would like to point out that the original code was vastly  inefficient. You are better off with this code (following the same logic):

```
static final char[] LETTERS = {'a', 'b', ..., '7', '8', '9'};
static final int WIDTH = LETTERS.length;
public static String generateRandomPassword()
{     
  char[] pw = new char[PASSWORD_LENGTH];
  for (int i=0; i<PASSWORD_LENGTH; i++)
  {
      pw[i] = LETTERS[RANDOM.nextInt(WIDTH)];
  }
  return new String(pw);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing a better way of generating :D